# Looking for a tool for external communication with jira integration

Tags: cloud, workflow, jira, integration, communication

I have a very specific question, maybe somebody knows anything.

We have a role within our company which would be the best described as a "External Consultant". We don't want to include those persons into jira because they need to be decoupled as far as possible from our internal processes to provide the best work.

Nonetheless we need to automatically communicate with them somehow when some Jira-Issues transition states.

We used to do so through Sending E-Mails through [Workflow Post Functions](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/modules/workflow-post-function/) and an E-Mail Addon.

Because E-Mails tend to lead to a big mess (when getting 5 mails for the same issue for example) we were thinking about using something like Slack where each Consultant has his own Channel and through JIRA Workflow Post Functions short Notifications are delivered to the specific Channels.

After some testing I found out that there is no way of sending Slack Notifications from a JIRA Post Function (tried a lot of addons). Now the big question: Does anybody know any different system like Slack which provides JIRA Integration?

[image: For better unterstanding here a BPMN Diagram indicating what I'm trying to achieve.]

The last solution would be to use some Zapier-Integrations but this would cause the system to get very complex.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [JIRA Misc Workflow Extensions](https://innovalog.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JMWE/overview) plugin to create a Groovy script that sends a Slack message via an incoming webhook upon issue transition?

Code example:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder("https://hooks.slack.com")
http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.TEXT) {
    uri.path = "/services/XXXX/YYYYY/ZZZZZ" 
    body = new JsonBuilder([
        channel   : "#dev",
        username  : "webhookbot",
        text      : "issue x has been updated", 
        icon_emoji: ":ghost:",
        mrkdwn    : true,
    ]).toString()
}
```

[(Code from a different plugin's site here)](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/listeners.html)

Comment: This would be the solution I've been thinking as well, the Problem is: It involves scripting. I'm really wondering why there is no UI-based Integration for that - same as for Mails (MailThis-Addon). Scripting in that case is a little bit dangerous because it Involves a lot of Copy & Paste and a person capable of creating such (little) scripts.  Btw it seems the JMWE-Addon does not support Groovy Scripts for Jira Cloud-Instances, only Jira Server.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! A UI-based integration would be great...